# Parsing and printing JSON data using Python

Tags: python, json, curl

I'm new to JSON and I'm working on extracting values from JSON data using Python. I'm getting the JSON data using another shell script with cURL.

Here is my JSON output from the shell script (Called test.sh):

```
{"preview":true,"offset":0,"result":{"Country":"AU","count":"417"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":1,"result":{"Country":"BG","count":"7"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":2,"result":{"Country":"CA","count":"198"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":3,"result":{"Country":"CH","count":"1"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":4,"result":{"Country":"CN","count":"3"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":5,"result":{"Country":"CR","count":"1"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":6,"result":{"Country":"DE","count":"148"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":7,"result":{"Country":"DK","count":"1"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":8,"result":{"Country":"FI","count":"1"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":9,"result":{"Country":"FR","count":"1052"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":10,"result":{"Country":"GB","count":"1430"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":11,"result":{"Country":"HK","count":"243"}}
{"preview":false,"offset":12,"lastrow":true,"result":{"Country":"VG","count":"54"}}
```

I want to print all the "Country" values and the "count" values to something like this:

```
AU 417
BG 7
CA 198
...
```

In order to do so, I created a loop to fetch and print all the needed values but I get this error:

```
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

This is my python code:

```
import subprocess
import json
import sys
import subprocess
answer = subprocess.check_output(['./test.sh']) #test.sh contains the cURL command
json_obj = json.load(answer)
for i in json_obj['result']:
    print i['Country']
    print i['count']
```

Am I missing something here ?

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you very much

Comment: You should be using `json.loads` if you have a string. Also note that your output isn't actually valid JSON (or, rather, it's multiple JSON objects, I think `json` will either only parse the first one or complain at you).

Comment: I think Python's json is very strict. Try putting true, false and numbers between quotes

Comment: @Goufalite true, false, numbers, etc. are all valid JSON values

Comment: @Goufalite and that's not the problem anyway.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I actually tried with json.loads too but I still get errors "ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 59 column 1 (char 68 - 4008)"

Comment: Yep, because you don't have a single valid JSON object. If you have multiple objects to return, put them in an array (i.e. starting with `[`, ending with `]` and with `,` between each one, like a Python list). Or `loads` it one line/object at a time.

Comment: @Felz This is because of what the other comments mentionned: Your json is not valid. Everything has to be in a single array.

Comment: The whole is not a valid json, you have one json per line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please save the code into `test.py` and data into `test.json`.

**test.py**

```
import json


with open('/tmp/test.json') as f:
    for i in f:
        data = json.loads(i)
        print("{Country} {count}".format(**data["result"]))
```

**test.json**

```
$ python test.py
AU 417
BG 7
CA 198
CH 1
CN 3
CR 1
DE 148
DK 1
FI 1
FR 1052
GB 1430
HK 243
VG 54
```

---

You can also try it in your prog:

```
for i in answer:
    data = json.loads(i)
    print("{Country} {count}".format(**data["result"]))
```

Comment: Thanks works like a charm ! I was confused since I thought the returned data was a single JSON object but I was wrong. TIL !

Answer (score 1):

I see several things either wrong or misinterpreted in the post:

1. If you have a collection of JSON objects, you should make them an array of objects, or parse them one at a time as separate files or separate lines in one file (not recommended). The former would be easier and more reliable:

   ```
   [{"obj":1},{"obj":2},...]
   ```
2. You should use `json.loads` and not `json.load` if you're loading directly from a string and not a file.
3. Here's a working example:

   ```
   import json

   answers = '[{"preview":true,"offset":0,"result":{"Country":"AU","count":"417"}}' + \
             ',{"preview":true,"offset":1,"result":{"Country":"BG","count":"7"}}]'
   json_obj = json.loads(answers)

   for i in json_obj:
       print i['result']['Country'], i['result']['count']
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For the result output

```
{"preview":true,"offset":0,"result":{"Country":"AU","count":"417"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":1,"result":{"Country":"BG","count":"7"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":2,"result":{"Country":"CA","count":"198"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":3,"result":{"Country":"CH","count":"1"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":4,"result":{"Country":"CN","count":"3"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":5,"result":{"Country":"CR","count":"1"}}
```

Actually there are lines of doc ( single json ).
You should read them line by line, not by all lines.

Here's the suggestion. You can temporarily save your JSON docs and then read them and load them.

1. save it `test.sh > tmp.txt`
2. read it line by line

`with open('tmp.txt', 'r') as f:
        for i in f:
            doc = f.readline()
            try:
                the_dict = json.loads(doc)
                print(the_dict['Country'])
            except Exception, e:
                print(str(e))`

Or if you insist on using subprocess, you can still read the file line by line. Just remember the output you got is a list. You should use a loop to iterate all of it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be,
Let's start with your answer:

```
answer = '''{"preview":true,"offset":0,"result":{"Country":"AU","count":"417"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":1,"result":{"Country":"BG","count":"7"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":2,"result":{"Country":"CA","count":"198"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":3,"result":{"Country":"CH","count":"1"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":4,"result":{"Country":"CN","count":"3"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":5,"result":{"Country":"CR","count":"1"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":6,"result":{"Country":"DE","count":"148"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":7,"result":{"Country":"DK","count":"1"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":8,"result":{"Country":"FI","count":"1"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":9,"result":{"Country":"FR","count":"1052"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":10,"result":{"Country":"GB","count":"1430"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":11,"result":{"Country":"HK","count":"243"}}
{"preview":false,"offset":12,"lastrow":true,"result":{"Country":"VG","count":"54"}}'''
```

convert it to a valid json

```
import json
answer = json.loads('['+answer.replace('\n',',')+']')
```

print your results:

```
for i in answer:
    print i['result']['Country'],i['result']['count']

AU 417
BG 7
CA 198
CH 1
CN 3
CR 1
DE 148
DK 1
FI 1
FR 1052
GB 1430
HK 243
VG 54
```

So your full code is:

```
import subprocess
import json
answer = subprocess.check_output(['./test.sh'])
answer = json.loads('['+answer.replace('\n',',')+']')
for i in answer:
    print i['result']['Country'],i['result']['count']
```

Answer (score -1):

Your data is multiple json objects.

You may want to wrap it in curly brackets (`{` and `}`) and treat it as one unique set of all your objects.

```
{
{"preview":true,"offset":0,"result":{"Country":"AU","count":"417"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":1,"result":{"Country":"BG","count":"7"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":2,"result":{"Country":"CA","count":"198"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":3,"result":{"Country":"CH","count":"1"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":4,"result":{"Country":"CN","count":"3"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":5,"result":{"Country":"CR","count":"1"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":6,"result":{"Country":"DE","count":"148"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":7,"result":{"Country":"DK","count":"1"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":8,"result":{"Country":"FI","count":"1"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":9,"result":{"Country":"FR","count":"1052"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":10,"result":{"Country":"GB","count":"1430"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":11,"result":{"Country":"HK","count":"243"}}
{"preview":false,"offset":12,"lastrow":true,"result":{"Country":"VG","count":"54"}}
}
```

Comment: That is completely invalid JSON. An array of objects should be used `[{},{},{}...]`