# Extracting JSON element

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON response from the website shown below. I want to print the `'value'` and `'datetime'` keys of `data`. I am not able to access these two elements in JSON response.

```
  data= {"parameter_name":"Inst",
    "parameter_code":"WL1","data":[
    {"value":3.1289999485,"datetime":"2018-07-01T00:00:00+00:00"},
    {"datetime":"2018-07-01T00:30:00+00:00","value":3.1859998703},
    {"value":3.33099985123,"datetime":"2018-07-01T00:45:00+00:00"},
    {"datetime":"2018-07-01T01:15:00+00:00","value":3.22300004959},
    {"datetime":"2018-07-01T01:45:00+00:00","value":3.32299995422}]}
```

my code till now

```
for element in len(data['data']):
            date = element['datetime']
            value = element['value']

            print value, date
```

I am getting error

```
for element in len(data['data']):
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've shown as your JSON `data` is *likely* not the actual value of `data`. If you attempt to access the data like a Python `dict`, it raises `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`. Your JSON `data` probably looks like this (notice the quotes):

```
# This is JSON, essentialy a string in the format of a Python dict.
data = """{
    "parameter_name": "Inst",
    "parameter_code": "WL1",
    "data":[
        {
            "value":3.1289999485,
            "datetime":"2018-07-01T00:00:00+00:00"
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2018-07-01T00:30:00+00:00",
            "value":3.1859998703
        },
        {
            "value":3.33099985123,
            "datetime":"2018-07-01T00:45:00+00:00"
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2018-07-01T01:15:00+00:00",
            "value":3.22300004959
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2018-07-01T01:45:00+00:00",
            "value":3.32299995422
        }
    ]
}"""
```

Convert it into a Python `dict` by using the Python Standard Library `json` package:

```
import json

# This converts the JSON string into a Python dict
data = json.loads(data)
```

You can access the `data` and it's 'data' key, then iterate over it (like you were doing):

```
for element in data['data']:
    print(element['value'], element['datetime'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. got it.  I also saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986406/parsing-and-printing-json-data-using-python

Comment: @gi.rajan Yep, same idea as that question/solution. Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
for element in data['data']:
    date = element['datetime']
    value = element['value']

print(date)
print(value)
```

Output:

```
3.1289999485
2018-07-01T00:00:00+00:00
3.1859998703
2018-07-01T00:30:00+00:00
3.33099985123
2018-07-01T00:45:00+00:00
3.22300004959
2018-07-01T01:15:00+00:00
3.32299995422
2018-07-01T01:45:00+00:00
```

Explanation:

If you want to iterate over the elements in the `list`,:

```
 for element in data['data']
```

If you want to iterate over the list using by their index:

```
 for index in range(len(data['data'])):
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a web responce in text format you would also have to decode it first. Check 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html (for python 2) or https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html (for python 3) to see the documentation about the `json` library.
You have to:

```
import json
decodedData = json.loads(data)
```

and then loop over decodedData as you've done.