# parse json data using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have this json data that i want to parse using python code

```
{  
   "_class":"com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsStoreAction$DomainWrapper",
   "credentials":[  
      {  
         "description":"",
         "displayName":"guest",
         "fingerprint":null,
         "fullName":"system/_/3fad6c4d-3f3a-48e1-9d7c-0f165e105907",
         "id":"3fad6c4d-3f3a-48e1-9d7c-0f165e105907",
         "typeName":"SSH Username with private key"
      },
      {  
         "description":"",
         "displayName":"guest",
         "fingerprint":null,
         "fullName":"system/_/9c078a40-bfce-44bb-96df-9014ac129036",
         "id":"9c078a40-bfce-44bb-96df-9014ac129036",
         "typeName":"SSH Username with private key"
      },
      {  
         "description":"",
         "displayName":"guest",
         "fingerprint":null,
         "fullName":"system/_/199b1b42-62a6-4859-ae94-c6ba832af693",
         "id":"199b1b42-62a6-4859-ae94-c6ba832af693",
         "typeName":"SSH Username with private key"
      },
      {  
         "description":"",
         "displayName":"guest",
         "fingerprint":null,
         "fullName":"system/_/35abdef0-c727-49c9-830a-8acb940a92cc",
         "id":"35abdef0-c727-49c9-830a-8acb940a92cc",
         "typeName":"SSH Username with private key"
      },...
```

and this data goes on.
I got this data from aJSON API and i want the values of display name, id and typeName from here but i am not sure how to proceed.

I am relatively new to python and could come up with this code

```
response = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=(user, api_token))
  response.status_code
#  print response.text
  json_data = response.json()
  print json_data
  resp_data = json.loads(credentials)
  resp_data['displayName']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing and printing JSON data using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986406/parsing-and-printing-json-data-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the credentials array and print the values you want.

```
response = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=(user, api_token))
response.status_code
json_data = response.json()
#iterate over credentials array
for credentials in json_data['credentials']:
    print(credentials['displayName'])
    print(credentials['id'])
    print(credentials['typeName'])
```

Comment: A typo... It would seem

Comment: well let's see, crtl-a to select ctrl-c to copy, and ctrl-v to paste. At least one of those has an a it it.. no?

Answer (score 2):

You were very close. You just need to iterate over the resp_data.

```
response = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=(user, api_token))
response.status_code
json_data = response.json()
resp_data = json_data['credentials']

for credential in resp_data:
    print(credential['displayName'], credential['id'], credential['typeName'], sep='---')
```

This should print out this response :

```
guest---SSH Username with private key---3fad6c4d-3f3a-48e1-9d7c-0f165e105907
guest---SSH Username with private key---9c078a40-bfce-44bb-96df-9014ac129036
guest---SSH Username with private key---199b1b42-62a6-4859-ae94-c6ba832af693
guest---SSH Username with private key---35abdef0-c727-49c9-830a-8acb940a92cc
```

In order to know more about working with JSON, you can reference this:
[Working With JSON Data in Python](https://realpython.com/python-json/)
and also this [JSON library official doc reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).